# How can I pass a channel through Dioxus router for cross-component communication?

Tags: rust, routes, components, dioxus

I'm trying to pass a channel from `App` to components through the Dioxus router so they can communicate between each other.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    dioxus_desktop::launch(App);
}

fn App(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    render! {
        style { include_str!("./style.css") },
        Router::<Route> {},
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Routable, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Route {
    #[route("/")]
    Login {},

    #[route("/chat")]
    Chat {
        name: String,
    },
}
```

I tried to use some kind of global and static state manager but the more I developed it the more complex it became and never got to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a channel to communicate between components, you can use the [use_coroutine](https://dioxuslabs.com/learn/0.4/reference/use_coroutine) hook. If you want shared state, you can use either [Fermi](https://docs.rs/fermi/latest/fermi/) or [use_shared_state](https://dioxuslabs.com/learn/0.4/reference/context).

If you want to try something experimental, you could even try the new [dioxus signals](https://github.com/DioxusLabs/dioxus/tree/master/packages/signals) crate on the git version of the framework. It can be used with the context API like use_shared_state, but should be more performant and it is always `Copy` regardless of the inner type